# I can't find android.test namespace

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to test a content provider using `ProviderTestCase2`. But I can't seem to be able to add the class.

I've started a new project using android 3.2 beta 5, open the sample android test file and try to extend the class from ProviderTestCase2.

I guess I am missing a gradle dependency but I can't figure it out.

Can you tell me what dependencies need to be added to a brand new android project in order to use `ProviderTestCase2`?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286876/2740621

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/training/testing/integration-testing/content-provider-testing

Comment: Thanks but I've also used at the docs.